# Scrapy returning a empty json file

Tags: python, json, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to get data from a website, everything seems to be correct and the xpath was tested on the shell.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider


class KabumspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "kabumspider"
    allowed_domain = ["www.kabum.com.br"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.kabum.com.br"]


def parse(self, response):
        categorias = response.xpath('//p[@class = "bot-categoria"]/a/text()').extract()
        links = response.xpath('//p[@class = "bot-categoria"]/a/@href').extract()

        for categoria in zip(categorias, links):

            info = {
                'categoria': categoria[0],
                'link': categoria[1],
            }
            yield info
```

Although, the output seems to be:

```
[
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: have you tried testing out the outputs in the scrapy shell? Also you should probably create items first, write the outputs to the item properties and write the items to the JSON file.

Comment: I did use items but I thought that that might have been the problem so I did it again that time using dictionaries... Everything seems to work just fine in the scrapy shell

Comment: if you put `print`s inside the for, can you see them? Also do you have any custom pipeline enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the scraper and it runs fine for me. The only issue i found is your parse method is outside the class.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider


class KabumspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "kabumspider"
    allowed_domain = ["www.kabum.com.br"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.kabum.com.br"]

    def parse(self, response):
        categorias = response.xpath('//p[@class = "bot-categoria"]/a/text()').extract()
        links = response.xpath('//p[@class = "bot-categoria"]/a/@href').extract()

        for categoria in zip(categorias, links):
            info = {
                'categoria': categoria[0],
                'link': categoria[1],
            }
            yield info
```

Comment: hahaha that was actually the error, i'm feeling embarrassed for making such a simple mistake